# Link with GET parameter

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

In a link you can append get parameters. If I want to add a new get parameter to a url which already has one.

Example: 
   old: example.php?hi=hello
   new: example.php?hi=hello&hello=hi

Is there any other way of doing it this way:

```
echo '<a href="'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&hello=hi">';
```

Comment: `echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&hello=hi">';`

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, but what I meant was if there is any other way than using  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: How do you mean simpler? Isn't that simple enough?

Comment: It is simple indeed, but is there any other way of doing it or is this the only way?

Comment: Your main issue is the question mark. If your incoming URL is `example.php` (no query string) and your resulting URL is `example.php&hello=hi` you're going to run into problems.

Comment: Well the URL the link is on already has a set query string. If it's removed it will reload the page with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caveat is detecting whether or not the question mark exists or not. If it doesn't, you'll need to add it. A quick and dirty way would be [strpos](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') === false) {
    $qsPart = '?';
} else {
    $qsPart = '&';
}

$oldURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '<a href="' . $oldURL . $qsPart . 'hello=hi">';
```

A more robust method would be breaking down the `REQUEST_URI` and rebuilding it after inspection using [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [http_build_query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) but that may be beyond the scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'hello' => 'hi',
    'hi' => 'hello',
);
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?' . http_build_query($params);
?>
<a href="<?php echo htmlentities($url); ?>">Link to tuther page</a>
```

As you are linking to the same page then you do not need to supply `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you can just supply the parameters like so to generate a relative URL:

```
<a href="?<?php echo htmlentities(http_build_query($params)); ?>">
    Link to tuther page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&hello=hi">';
```

Or you could make a function which accepts as many paramaters as you want.

```
<?php
$urlArray = array('value'=>'key', 'hi' => 'hello');
$url ='example.php';
function urlGenerator($url,$urlArray){
foreach ($urlArray as $key => $value) {
    if($i==0){
    $url .= '?'.$key.'='.$value;
    }else{
    $url .= '&'.$key.'='.$value;    
    }
    $i++;
}
return $url;
}
echo urlGenerator($url,$urlArray);
//Output: example.php?value=key&hi=hello
```

Comment: I hadn't realised you were just trying to access the current URL. I'll leave this anyway incase it is of any use. Otherwise see @webbiedave comment.